# Javascript confirm Stop page refresh after cancel

Tags: javascript

I have made a JavaScript function which is attached to the cancel button on of a form. The issue I am finding is that when the cancel button is pressed the page/form reloads losing the data in the text fields.

```
    function cancelConfirm(){
    var confirmCancel = confirm("Are you sure you wish to cancel?");
    if(confirmCancel==true)
    {
    alert("byebye");
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }
    };
```

I was just wondering how can you prevent the page from reloading after the cancel button on the confirm has been clicked? Thanks for any help you can give

Comment: your code looks fine, it must be doing postback when you press ok after confirm box, right?

Comment: Thanks I have canceled the post back on the onlick call from the button and it has works

Answer (score 1):

```
function cancelConfirm() {
    var confirmCancel = confirm("Are you sure you wish to cancel?");
    if (confirmCancel == true) {
        alert("byebye");
        return false;// to stop postback on ok cick of confirmation popup
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use a simple way

```
<a href="" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure!!!!')">Delete </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to add an onClick event and pass the event object down to it.

```
{onClick(event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  //do something here
}}
```

A simple `event.preventDefault()` is what you need.

Comment: Please add some more content. For example, you could elaborate on why this is necessary and what `e` is and does. You could also add a code snippet and/or explain how OP should implement it.